# Sequelize ts error. Argument of type '"long"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TextDataTypeOptions'

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model, BuildOptions } from 'sequelize';

...

client_data: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT('long'),
    allowNull: false
}
```

I searched everything I can find and they say this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"` and `postgresql`, short answer:

It should be `DataTypes.TEXT({ length: 'long' })`; The parameter interface of the `DataTypes.TEXT()` method is below:

`data-types.d.ts`:

```js
export interface TextDataTypeOptions {
  length?: TextLength;
}
```

Long answer, a completed working example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

class SomeEntity extends Model {}
SomeEntity.init(
  {
    client_data: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT({ length: 'long' }),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'SomeEntities' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

After executing the above code, using `\d[S+]  NAME` of `psql` cli find the information on columns of `SomeEntities` relation:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# \d "SomeEntities"
                             Table "public.SomeEntities"
   Column    |  Type   |                          Modifiers
-------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer | not null default nextval('"SomeEntities_id_seq"'::regclass)
 client_data | text    | not null
Indexes:
    "SomeEntities_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The data type of `client_data` column is `text` as exepcted.

The execution debug message:

```sh
{ POSTGRES_HOST: '127.0.0.1',
  POSTGRES_PORT: '5430',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'testpass',
  POSTGRES_USER: 'testuser',
  POSTGRES_DB: 'node-sequelize-examples' }
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "SomeEntities" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "SomeEntities" CASCADE;
(sequelize) Warning: PostgreSQL does not support TEXT with options. Plain `TEXT` will be used instead. 
>> Check: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype.html
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SomeEntities" ("id"   SERIAL , "client_data" TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'SomeEntities' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
```